# Minimal Busybox/Linux Installation - Won't Run C

Tags: linux, compiling, embedded, c, busybox

I'm trying my hand at creating a very minimal custom Busybox/Linux distro, a task that is admittedly above my head, but I figured I'd give it a shot. My issue is that whenever I try to run a C program that is not Busybox or a Busybox utility, ash complains and tells me that the file is not found. I mounted the partition from my Arch system, installed GNU binutils and uClibc; no dice. I also wrote the simplest C program I could think of with no dependencies on any libraries:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled, ran on Arch, still gave me "file not found" on my Busybox system, although it is shown when I run ls. To address the obvious, yes, I ran it from the same directory as the program and typed `./` before the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have the correct dynamic linker on the Busybox system.

On your Arch system do this:
    ldd ./simplestprogram

I imagine `ldd` will give you output similar to this:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9b34f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003b19e00000
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b19a00000)
```

That last line, `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is the dynamic linker. I bet that isn't present on your Busybox system.

I compiled a "hello, world" program on my Arch laptop, used `vim` in binary mode to change `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to `/lib65/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, saved it, and tried to execute it. I got the same "file not found" message you got.

You may not even have the `libc.so` file on your Busybox system. It's possible that just copying the `libc.so` and dynamic linker files from Arch to Busybox systems (preserving directories!) might work, but it might not. I'm just not sure.

One thing to try: install `musl` on your Arch machine. Compile your simple program with `musl-gcc -static -o simple simple.c`, move that executable, which has no dynamically-linked anything, and try it on the Busybox system.

Comment: It is an embedded system. Things are built in a different way, or so I think. Is it supposed to be adding more components to it?

Comment: It's not an embedded system, actually. I'm just trying to create the smallest system I reasonably can. I have no objection to adding more components if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build or install a uClibc toolchain and compile/link your programs with that. You do not compile them with the standard gcc/make/....

[Do I really need to build a uClibc toolchain?](https://www.uclibc.org/FAQ.html#toolchain)

Comment: I cannot be of much more help here, I only used toolchains to cross-compile for NetBSD in ARM from an Intel Linux.